# Поиск элемента в QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, qt, model, sqlite

Есть `QSqlTableModel`, связанная с таблицей в базе данных.
Нужно найти элемент(получить его индекс), находящийся в столбце "column" и для которого значение в первом столбце равно "value". Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я делаю у себя простой функцией самописной

```
int get_ncurr(QString name_id, QTableView *tbl, QSqlTableModel *model)
{
    int row;
    int n_curr;
    QSqlRecord curr;

    row = tbl->currentIndex().row();
    curr = model->record(row);
    n_curr = curr.value(name_id).toInt();
    return n_curr;
}
```

Comment: Похоже на костыль

Comment: это не костыль, а инструмент. Вы вообще нрчего подобного не можете изобразить и понять. Вот вам и не отвечают, что бы не пачкаться